# Preload a modal view controller

Tags: objective-c

There's a way to preload a modal view controller without showing it? 
I'm asking because when I'm displaying the modal view controller (allocating and initializing the view controller class), the view have a little delay to load and display.
After it, when I try to show it again, the delay stops.

I'm using a `UITableView`, and inside the method `scrollViewDidEndDragging` I check if the `contentOffset.y` is less than -90. If so, the user basically "pulled to refresh", then I'm loading the view.

Comment: PS: I know that there's a lot of questions like this one, but no one shows a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `UINib` to preload the XIB into memory.

It will pre-decode the object-tree of the XIB into memory, but won't instantiate the objects in the XIB. Then you can call the `instantiate` method of `UINib` to instanciate the view.

- You can also force the `view` of a `UIViewController` to be loaded by calling its `view` getter method (as the view is lazy-loaded, so it will be loaded from the XIB the first time it is accessed).

But as you can only instantiate UI objects (from your XIB) on the main thread -- as every UI component and UI action has to be done in the main thread -- your app will still "freeze" (block the main thread) while you load the view. You can't for example load the root UIView of your XIB in a separate thread or queue (you will have an runtime exception if you try that).

---

Use **Instruments** and its "Time Profiler" tool to check where exactly the loading process of your XIB file takes time. *(Maybe it is easy enough to resolve, or maybe you will have some component that you can lazy-load only after the view has been displayed, etc.)*

Comment: Actually not really solved. I'm accepting it as an right answer because of your tip of accessing the Time Profiler, that really helped me to realize that no matter what the view will still freeze (even milliseconds).

Comment: Yep but as explained, no matter what you will try, loading UI elements from a XIB must/can always be done on the main thread only and not on a separate thread/queue, as for any manipulation of UI elements. So you won't be able to load you XIB without freezing the main thread while the UI elements are loading, so this is kinda unsolvable. The only pseudo-solution is to solve the cause of the slow loading itself if you manage to solve it (e.g. if some implementation of one of your own `awakeFromNib` overrides takes too much time, or whatever other code you can tweak)

Answer (score 0):

you could call the viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad by hand.

Comment: Calling `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` won't load anything from the XIB. calling the `view` getter method will, as the view of a `UIViewController` is lazy-loaded (only loaded from the XIB when first needed) so querying it explicitly will load it from the XIB. But anyway, you will only be able to do this on the main thread (as all UI loading has to be done in the main thread) so this will still freeze the UI at some point (only earlier, when you call the `view` getter method and force-load the view, instead of when you ask the `UIViewController` to be displayed)

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the contents of the view on viewWillAppear and then show it.

Alternatively you can load all the properties of the modalview and then show it with a method. Making the view a property.

Comment: I already tried it and looks like that the delay don't stopped. Take a look at the edit. As I'm trying to load a view when the user stop dragging, a delay of 0.2 seconds is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could try accessing the view, this will make the viewDidLoad method to get called, although this is not the way things should be done...

```
//Preload
YourViewController * controller = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

.
.
.
.

//Load Controller after time
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Note that this will still block the main thread and freeze the app while loading the view. The only difference is that it will freeze earlier, at the time you access the `view` property, not at the time you call the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method.

Comment: Then you don't need to preload it, you need to make your code faster

Comment: I started coding yesterday, and I don't have more than 30 lines of own code.

Comment: Note that there is no point in preloading the `Controller` in the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` in order to see any improvement you could put it in the mainController ViewDidLoad or in the AppDelegate, but as  AliSoftware says it will block the UI, so you have to analize which is the place of your app when the user won't notice it.