# UIBarButtonItems shift position when UINavigationController is presented modally

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm presenting a `UINavigationController` modally, from within an iOS app extension:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];       
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the navigation controller appears, its root view controller's `UIBarButtonItems` jump position:

[image: Jumping buttons]

I'm creating and adding the buttons in `viewDidLoad`. They are just standard bar button items:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
```

I'm not overriding `viewDidAppear` (which appears to be the point where the buttons jump).

Presenting this same navigation controller/root view controller from within my app, instead of the app extension, doesn't give me this same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here- thought it was a problem with using a custom font with default appearances for all `UIBarButtonItem`s, but I took away the custom font and it kept happening! I'm calling my modal from a `DDMenuController` and the issue definitely did not appear in iOS7. I'm not even setting the `modalPresentationStyle` or `modalTransitionStyle`.

Comment: As a side-note, I do get the console message "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UINavigationController: 0x155e15640>" every time I present a VC modally. I've tried presenting from the `DDMenuController` and from its root controller but I get the message either way. Perhaps this is the reason it is discouraged?

Comment: @Stonz2 In `viewWillAppear`, try calling `[self.view setNeedsLayout]; [self.view layoutIfNeeded];`.

Comment: @LeoNatan Nope. Still shifting upon presentation.

Comment: Maybe you should try a preload of your modalView : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782841/preload-a-modal-view-controller

Comment: @Ludovic Seems like they're trying to preload the view simply by calling some sort of operation on it before presentation. I tried setting the bar button item from the caller (so that it is set before presentation) and changed the background of `myModalView.view` before presenting, and neither one did anything (with or without the `setNeedsLayout` suggestion above)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded do not fix it.

Comment: I'm having this issue only in share extension.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping someone else finds a better way to do this, but my current solution is to create stand alone buttons and then use `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:]` with the button. Not ideal, and the indention is still there, but the weird jump doesn't happen anymore.

If the indention bothers you, you could also set negative fixed spaces on the outsides of the buttons to shift them closer to the edges.

Here's an example including the spacer:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
<other button config here, set targets, whatever>
[button sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedSpace setWidth:-8.0f];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[fixedSpace, leftBarButton];
```

This only happens to me on my share extension, and I don't have any problems related to presenting from a detached controller or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks. Due to this solutions some how you made my day

Answer (score 2):

As @Stonz2 mentioned, this appears to be a characteristic of presenting a modal from a detached view controller. I was having the same problem and remedied it by re-organizing my app so that it wasn't presenting from a detached controller.

You'll know if you're presenting from a detached controller if you get the following error message:

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Comment: I have the issue but i'm not getting "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" message.

Answer (score 0):

I was presenting from a detached viewController.  I never got the warning. But I tried embedding that detached viewController in a NavigationController, and the problem went away.